# how do i find the time complexity (big O) of this triple loop?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory, code-complexity

```
for (int i = 0; i < n^2; i++) {
  for (int j = 1; j < i; j = 2j) {
    for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
      System.out.println("x");
    }
  }
}
```

My thoughts are that the outer loop is n^2, middle loop is log(n) and inner loop is n so that means the total time complexity is O(n^3 * log(n)) but I'm not sure if this is right.

Comment: "inner loop is n" Not really. Inner loop executes j times, where j changes in an interesting way.

Comment: Your question is meaningless without the loop. Delete the whole question if you like, but not just the part that it’s about.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of the following nested loop:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < n^2; i++) {
  for (int j = 1; j < i; j = 2j) {
    for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
      System.out.println("x");
    }
  }
}
```

...is O(<sup>4</sup>):

The value of `n` is only used in `n^2`, so let's define `m=n^2`

The first two iterations of the outer loop do nothing (the j-loop condition is immediately false), so we can start at 2 instead of 0.

The print statement is an O(1) operation, so the inner loop is O().

We can then write the code like this:

```java
for (int i = 2; i < m; i++) {
  for (int j = 1; j < i; j = 2j) {
    O(j)
  }
}
```

Now let's rewrite the j-loop defining `p` as `log(j)` (all logarithms here have base 2):

```java
for (int i = 2; i < m; i++) {
  int q = ceil(log(i))
  for (int p = 0; p < q; p++) {
    O(2^p)
  }
}
```

the inner loop's complexity represents a [geometric sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) so it has a closed formula, and we can rewrite:

```java
for (int i = 2; i < m; i++) {
  int q = ceil(log(i))
  O(2^q)
}
```

The loop's body will have repeatedly the same value for `q` for some different values of `i` until `i` overtakes the next power of 2. We could introduce a variable `q` equal to `ceil(log(i))`, which makes its own iterations:

```java
for (int q = 1; q <= ceil(log(m)); q++) {          
  for (int i = 2^(q-1) + 1; i <= 2^q && i < m; i++) {
    O(2^q)
  }
}
```

As the value of `i` doesn't matter anymore for the inner loop, we can use its number of iterations as a coefficient for the big Oh expression:

```java
for (int q = 1; q <= ceil(log(m)); q++) {
  O(2^(q-1) * 2^q)
}
```

To be fair, the condition `i < m` would limit the number of iterations of the previous inner loop when the outer loop is in its last iteration, but asymptotically this is not significant.

We can simplify:

```java
for (int q = 1; q <= ceil(log(m)); q++) {
  O(4^q)
}
```

Which is again a geometric sequence, summing up to:

O(4<sup>log()</sup>)

= O([2<sup>log()</sup>]<sup>2</sup>)

= O(<sup>2</sup>)

= O(<sup>4</sup>)

Comment: I make it *O(N^2(log^2(N)).* Inner loop is linear in *j*, which is *O(log(N^2)*, which is *O(2*log(N))*, which ignoring the constant factor is *O(log(N))* still. So you have *O(N^2)* for the outer loop, times *O(log(N))* for the middle loop, times *O(log(N))* again for the inner loop.

Comment: @user207421, If you have a different answer, then why not post it as an answer? This comment section is for commenting on my answer. But in short, the middle loop is not O(logN). You're making more than one mistake here. Just read the proof I have provided.